# Tool-rich image editor for Android

Tags: android, image-editing

I need a decent image editor for Android.

I don't care about effects.

What I need is eraser tool, crop tool, rectangular selection tool, circular selection tool, lasso tool, brush tool, pencil tool, text tool, paint bucket tool, shapes tool...

All that a decent image editor should have

And of course: doesn't demand login, clouds, whatever, and I can Save As locally!

No app on the market seem to do that.

Comment: Autodesk Sketchbook is the one that approaches a little a decent app. Thread still open, though